# Query related to month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains Year and Month as columns like below:-

```
Id Year Month Value

1  2012 12    100

2  2013 1     200

3  2013 2     300

4  2013 12    200

5  2012 11    200
```

I want to create a query which gives me values with **(year >= 2012 and month >= 12)** and also **(year =< 2013 and month =< 12)** i.e. It should give me Id 1, 2, 3, 4.

**EDIT**

This is just an example to demonstrate the behavior.
The months and Year might vary. So please create an answer that suits the condition for any year and any month that are passed.

How can I create a query with the following condition?

Regards
Vishal

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: So you want everything with year 2013 except month 12? i.e. for year 2013 months 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, and 11?

Comment: Also how will Id = 1 be in the result if `year > 2012 and month > 12`?

Comment: your first pseudo query says year > 2012 and month > 12...  do you mean month < 12?

Comment: Your conditions make no sense. If it's really `AND` between the two your result would be empty. If it's `OR` you'll get everything that's not in month 12.

Comment: @shadowjfaith i want 2012 12 month abd 2013 1 to 12 month data.

Comment: @user2989408 Please check the edit made to the question. I meant lees than or equal and greater than or equal

Comment: @ps2goat I took a specific example of the month 12, it can be anything from 1 to 12. I gave you something specific to work with.

Comment: ok. i was just saying that logic would never do anything.

Comment: Why don't you create a DATE column and store the beginning of the month, instead of storing year and month separately? Then your where clause can be a lot more like the English you wrote.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think so too, I think what he needs is that the row be created in the past 13 months.

Comment: @AaronBertrand We want to specifically highlight the values i.e. the activities happened in the whole month instead of a single date.

Comment: @vishal parameterizing your query should happen in your program. It's impossible to give a generic SQL statement that fits all year/month combinations. Especially since the scheme is still unclear (at least to me).

Comment: You can still do that with a DATE.

Comment: @vishal You can easily accomplish this with a `DATETIME` column still.  Your new code would be something like `WHERE NewDateCol BETWEEN 12/1/2012 AND 12/31/2013`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @YearFrom int, @YearTo int, @MonthFrom int, @MonthTo int
set @YearFrom = 2012
set @YearTo = 2013
set @MonthFrom = 12
set @MonthTo = 12

select ID, YEAR, MONTH, Value 
from [yourtable]
WHERE (year = @yearfrom AND month >= @monthfrom or year > @yearfrom) 
AND (year = @yearto AND month <= @monthto or year < @yearto)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you want

```
SELECT id 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE (Year = '2013' OR (Year = '2012' AND Month = '12'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your conditions now ("i want 2012 12 month abd 2013 1 to 12 month data"):

```
SELECT Id FROM TableName WHERE (Year = 2012 AND Month = 12) OR (Year = 2013) ORDER BY Id
```

This is assuming there can't be a month > 12 or < 1 ;-)

Comment: Would fail for `year = 2012 AND month = 11`

Comment: @stonedsquirrel great minds think alike.

Comment: @shadowjfaith indeed :D

Answer (score 0):

**edit based on comment**

For a given @yearIN

```
select * from table 
where (year = @yearIN and month != 12) or (year = (@yearIN-1) and month = 12)
```

---

I think this is what you want

```
select * from table 
where (year = 2013 and month != 12) or (year = 2012 and month = 12)
```

I think this makes the logic of what you are looking for clearer -- I expect you don't want the last month of 2011

Comment: this becomes a specific condition. I am looking for a dynamic condition that would work for all scenarios. Even if i go with any month and any year.

Comment: @vishal - you have to tell us what you mean by "all scenarios".  Do you mean for a given fiscal year (eg 2013 above)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to convert the columns to a bigger integer (or string).  Assuming the values are integers:

```
select id
from table
where year*100+month between 201212 and 201312;
```